# Why Android Gradle preDexDebug "Source and destination must be different" build failed?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android application built with Android Studio 0.8.1 and facing the issue:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source C:\Users\mfedorov\AndroidStudioProjects\EPOS2\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\mate-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-0ef7e3259aeaf19202f545da97dc6b1ae2502c9a.jar and destination C:\Users\mfedorov.ALTIUS-PLUS\AndroidStudioProjects\EPOS2\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\mate-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-0ef7e3259aeaf19202f545da97dc6b1ae2502c9a.jar must be different
```

Here's my build.gradle file contents (the part that I have changed, the rest is default)

```
configurations.all {
    // check for updates every build
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.7'
    compile 'com.altius.logging:logging-utils:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compile group: "com.altius.mate", name: "mate-bluetooth", version: "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", changing: true
    compile group: "com.altius.mate", name: "mate-api", version: "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", changing: true
    //compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
    //exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    //exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    //}

}
```

contents of the root build.gradle are default as created with android project

mate-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT artifacts are from Maven local repository `mavenLocal()`

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project?

Comment: Goto **Build -> Clean Project** and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The answer was just to clean the project. I was having same problem for some time.

> **Build** -> **Clean Project**

Comment: This did not do it for me, I also had to delete all /build folders manually.

Comment: I had to run the clean commands from the Gradle tool window in IntelliJ IDEA. Build -> Clean Project did not work.

Comment: Didn't help in my case :/ Had to remove dependency on hamcrest-all.jar (used by LambdaJ): https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/issues/detail?id=145

Comment: happened for me for a "gradle clean build" - so clean is not really helping - seems to be a bug. Interestingly a second "gradle clean build" went fine ..

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on Android Studio 2.1.2 Build #AI_143.2915827.

Comment: It's not helping, I am unable to compile my project on Android Studio 4.0.

Comment: I had to delete both the build and .cxx folders and regenerate, but eventually worked.  I believe it happened because I was adding build targets incrementally and there was some old pathing lying around confusing things.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the build folder in your project and invalidate cache in android studio, restart android studio