# How to use the dropbox android core API on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dropbox, dropbox-api

There aren't any instructions on the dropbox site on how you set up a project on android studio, they only have instruction for eclipse! Could someone tell me how you're supposed to import all the library files in the zip file(downloaded from the dropbox site:dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3) onto android studio?
I tried importing the files in libs and adding them as libraries, while the classes are recognised I get compile errors.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.dropboxconnecttest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.client2.android.AndroidAuthSession;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    final static private String APP_KEY = "key";
    final static private String APP_SECRET = "secret";

    // In the class declaration section:
    private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // And later in some initialization function:
        AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair("key", "secret");
        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys);
        mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

        mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(MainActivity.this);

    }


    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                // Required to complete auth, sets the access token on the session
                mDBApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();

                String accessToken = mDBApi.getSession().getOAuth2AccessToken();
                Log.i("on resume","Successful");
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.i("DbAuthLog", "Error authenticating", e);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ashwinpraveen1.dropboxconnecttest" >



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
                <data android:scheme="db-key" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

The compile errors:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
:app:preDexDebug
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$4) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$5) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$6) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
trouble processing "java/awt/font/NumericShaper.class":
Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.
However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.
If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.
If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 22.371 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ashwinpraveen1.dropboxconnecttest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/android.jar')
    compile files('libs/bcprov-jdk16-146.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/junit-4.10.jar')


}
```

Comment: Copy all the necessary `.jar` files into `yourproject/app/libs` folder and then also edit `gradle.build` to set dependencies and then sync your project again.

Comment: @Apurva I already tried that, I'm getting the error above.

Comment: show the your `build.gradle`!

Comment: @anderson_acs I have just added the file above.

Comment: @AshwinPraveen Ok, make sure to sync the  your project to gradle update all dependencies

Comment: @anderson_acs I have updated and synced the file.

Comment: try to compile without this libs files  `compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar') `and  `compile files('libs/junit-4.10.jar')`

Comment: @anderson_acs still getting an error

Comment: @AshwinPraveen The same error? you removed the libs from the lib folder too?

Comment: @anderson_acs this is the error I get: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source /Users/ashwinpraveen1/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/DropboxConnectTest/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/httpclient-4.0.3-63eee523924457404bc4ff5e8b79ac29343dac7c.jar and destination /Users/ashwinpraveen1/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/DropboxConnectTest/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/httpclient-4.0.3-63eee523924457404bc4ff5e8b79ac29343dac7c.jar must be different

Comment: Ok, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886630/why-android-gradle-predexdebug-source-and-destination-must-be-different-build

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104784/how-to-import-dropbox-chooser-sdk-in-android-studio 

It covers a similar problem to yours.