# How to import dropbox Chooser SDK in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, dropbox, dropbox-api

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/android

I am trying to use the android chooser in Android Studio but I not sure how to import it to my project and user it. I am using Android Studio, not Eclipse Android Studio if that has any relevance. I just have no idea how to being the unzipped file into use in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's more complex than it ought to be, but this procedure worked for more than just the Dropbox SDK.**

1. Unzip the Dropbox Chooser SDK somewhere
2. Open your project in Android Studio
3. Create a new sub-directory "libraries" (right-click -> new -> directory)
4. Create a new module in the libraries directory (right-click -> new -> module)
5. In the "New Module" window, from "More Modules" select "Android Library"
6. Click Next
7. Edit "Library name" to "dropbox-chooser"
8. Edit module name to "dropbox-chooser"
9. Edit package name to "com.dropbox.chooser.android"
10. Click next until done
11. Navigate to "libraries/dropbox-chooser/src/main"
12. Delete everything within the "java" and "res" directories, but do not remove the directories
13. Navigate to the directory where you have unzipped the SDK
14. Copy everything in the "src" directory to the "java" directory of the new module
15. Replace the "res" directory in the new module, with the one from the SDK
16. Do the same with AndroidManifest.xml

**Now, to reference the library in your main project:**

1. Open/Create "settings.gradle" in your main project dir
2. Add *include 'libraries:dropbox-chooser'* to the file
3. In build.gradle, withing the dependencies section add *compile project(':libraries:dropbox-chooser')*

This should do the trick.
Sync, build, and all should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up doing it a similar way. Hopefully this will help some other developers in the future!

Answer (score 3):

The Dropbox developers page now includes documentation on how to use the Chooser SDK with Android Studio.

Basically, you create a module from the SDK, and then you add it as a dependency to your project.

Detailed steps are described here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/android

Comment: Thank you very much, I did end up doing something along these lines. I had a project due around the time when I posted this and finished up the project without thinking of posting how I resolved it !