# Android preDex source and destination classes.dex must be different

Tags: android, android-multidex

My project is made up of 2 modules: a library, and an actual application.
If I add productFlavors to my library modules, the second time I try to run the app I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDevDebug'.
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source /app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/dev/debug/classes-1d938e14549827f08a7a5e52ff3458d568bf7342.jar/classes.dex and destination /app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/dev/debug/classes-1d938e14549827f08a7a5e52ff3458d568bf7342.jar/classes.dex must be different

If I remove the following lines from the library's build.gradle file everything works fine:

```
defaultPublishConfig "developmentDebug"
publishNonDefault true

productFlavors {
    production {
        minSdkVersion 15
    }

    development {
        minSdkVersion 22
    }
}
```

The same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886630/why-android-gradle-predexdebug-source-and-destination-must-be-different-build). Cleaning the project makes the project run the first time, but still crashes the second time I run the app.
Any ideas?